# redirect page with header with string

Tags: php, redirect

My page cannot redirect to another page using `header` and below is the code

```
$v1 = "http://www.google.com";

header('Location: $v1');
```

instead it redirected to `http://localhost/$v1`

How can i achieve this type of syntax to redirect

Answer (score 4):

Change single quote to double quotes. Note that variables inside the single quotes would not be parsed.

```
header("Location: $v1");
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax. Try:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/";
header("Location: $url");
//     ^              ^
// You should use double quotes to expand variables.
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$v1 = "http://www.google.com";
header('Location:'. $v1);
```